# Finding documents where an array of sub-documents is a subset of a given search term

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I have these documents in my collection:

```
{ foo: [ {bar: 1, baz: 2}, {bar: 3, baz: 4} ] }
{ foo: [ {bar: 5, baz: 6}, {bar: 7, baz: 8} ] }
```

Each document contains an array `foo` of sub-documents. Now, this query allows me to find all documents where `foo` is a superset of `[{bar: 1, baz: 2}, {bar: 3, baz: 4}]`, i.e. where all of the given (sub) documents are in the `foo` array:

```
db.examples.find({
  $and: [
    { foo: { $elemMatch: { bar: 1, baz: 2 } } },
    { foo: { $elemMatch: { bar: 3, baz: 4 } } }
  ]
})
```

This returns the first document as expected.

However, how would I go about finding the documents were `foo` is a *subset* of the given search term? Meaning, my search term is:

```
[{bar: 1, baz: 2}, {bar: 3, baz: 4}, {bar: 5, baz: 6}]
```

And I want it to match the first document in the collection, but not the second (all sub-documents in `foo` must be in the given search term).

Comment: Did you try *[mongo Set Operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation-set/)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$elemMatch` with `$nor` selects all the documents with `foo` sub documents not matching search term and `$not` to select the documents where `foo` sub documents is subset of search term.

You can use `$nin` instead of `$nor` too.

You may want to include `$exist` condition if you have sub documents that don't contain the search fields.

```
db.examples.find({
    foo: {
        $not: {
            $elemMatch: {
                $nor: [{bar: 1,baz: 2},{bar: 3,baz: 4}, {bar: 5,baz: 6}]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make your search term a two dimensional array that looks like this.

```
let searchTerms = [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ];
```

This is because as you know, [an object is an unordered set of name/value pairs](http://www.json.org/).

From there you need to use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact) operator to perform a logical [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond)ition processing.

Your condition here is as [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact) which returns true when the element in the "input" array is a subset of your `searchTerms` array.

When `$setIsSubset` returns true, you [`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) the document and discard it when it returns false using the [`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) variable.

Of course the first expression in the `$setIsSubset` needs to resolve to a two dimensional array like your "searchTerms" array. And to do that, you need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map) array operator which allows you to apply an expression to each subdocuments in the "foo" array. The expression here uses the `[]` operator new in version 3.2 to return a 2d array where the first element in each sub-array is the the value of "bar" and the last element the value of "bar".

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
            { "$setIsSubset": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$foo", 
                    "as": "f", 
                    "in": [ "$$f.bar", "$$f.baz" ]}
                }, 
                searchTerms
            ]}, 
            "$$KEEP", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ]
    }}
])
```

Finally, note that `$redact` does not use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) in the aggregation pipeline.

```
db.example.aggregate([
    {
        $project : {
            foo : 1,
            criteria : {
                $literal : [{bar: 1, baz: 2}, {bar: 3, baz: 4}, {bar: 5, baz: 6}]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            foo : 1,
            subset : {
                $setIsSubset : ["$foo", "$criteria"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match : {
            subset : true
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            foo : 1
        }
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ..., "foo" : [ { "bar" : 1, "baz" : 2 }, { "bar" : 3, "baz" : 4 } ] }
```

Note: You can use a `$match` phase before first `$project` that may use an index.

Comment: You answer assume that the order of key in the subdocument and the objects in the "searchTerms" array is the always the same which is not true because key/paris value are unordered in JSON. So you query will fail to find the document if you pass something like: `[{baz:2, bar: 1}, {bar: 3, baz: 4}, {bar: 5, baz: 6}]`

Comment: Yes, the order is irrelevant in JSON but relevant in BSON. However, OP didn't mention that order change of fields to be considered. Furthermore, the example query posted by OP also assumes that the order in subdocuments will remain same.

Comment: The example query uses `$elemMatch`, which uses a complete document-matching sub query, i.e. the same workings as `find({ foo: 'bar', baz: 42 })`. I can confirm that your solution is too brittle unfortunately, though it does look very promising.